# Using CTE to get the hierarchy of emp regardless the position

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking into creating a hierarchy query using CTE. However, I am missing something on the where clause, the query should return the full hierarchy of an employee

Here is **[a SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fee35/1)** that I have created.

Expected results:

For `id = 3` I should get these results:

```
ParentEmpId Id          Name 
----------- ----------- -----
NULL        1           A    
1           3           C    
3           6           F
```

For `id = 2`, I should get these results:

```
ParentEmpId Id          Name 
----------- ----------- -----
NULL        1           A    
1           2           B    
2           4           D     
2           5           E
```

Comment: Are you trying to get both children and parents of an `id`? because if you only need the hierarchy of parents of an `id`, the output would differ from your expected output.

Comment: There are a few different ways you could do this. Perhaps the simplest way would be to have one heirarchical CTE for an ID's children and one hierarchical CTE for an ID's parent(s) and then union the CTEs.

Comment: @rad: yes I am trying to get parents and children for a given I'd.

Comment: @ZLK:make sense, is that the only solution?

Comment: No, but it might be the simplest way. Others I can think of would require looping over a single CTE twice anyway (once to find anything related to an id and once to pull out the data). For example, you could add a column to the CTE that contains a comma-separated list of all the ids in the hierarchy sequence then do a string split on that to pull IDs then join back to the CTE (or the original table if you don't care about levels). There might be a way to make it more efficient than two CTEs, but two CTEs is more straight-forward IMO.

Comment: Here's a quick example of how one might take that approach (though there are probably ways to get better performance with similar ideas): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fee35/82

Comment: While my mind was wandering at lunch, I also considered that you could do this with the `hierarchyid` data type. For example, another possible solution can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fee35/90 (though practically, unless your table is of a rather substantial size, it doesn't matter which method you go with in terms of performance - it's more about which is more readable/intuitive to you if you ever need to do maintenance).

Comment: @ZLK: The last query is fantastic, the level are working fine. Thank's

Answer (score 2):

From your expected output it seems that you need both children and parents of an `id`. Therefore, you need one hierarchy for children and one for parents:

```
WITH EmpCTE(ParentEmpId, Id, [Name], [Level]) AS
(
    SELECT ParentEmpId, Id, [Name], 0 AS [Level]
    FROM emp
    WHERE id=3
         UNION ALL
    SELECT E.ParentEmpId, E.Id, E.[Name], [Level] + 1
    FROM emp E
        INNER JOIN EmpCTE empCTE
        ON E.Id = EmpCTE.ParentEmpId 
),
 EmpCTE2(ParentEmpId, Id, [Name], [Level]) AS
(
    SELECT ParentEmpId, Id, [Name], 0 AS [Level]
    FROM emp
    WHERE id=3
         UNION ALL
    SELECT E.ParentEmpId, E.Id, E.[Name], [Level] + 1
    FROM emp E
        INNER JOIN EmpCTE2 empCTE2
        ON E.ParentEmpId = EmpCTE2.Id 
)
Select * from (
select * from EmpCTE 
Union 
select * from EmpCTE2 ) a
order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

The current CTE that you are using generates the *descending* hierarchy of the given `id`, not the *parent* hierarchy.

One solution would be to create a second recursive CTE to generate the parent hierarchy, and then `UNION` both, as follows:

```
WITH EmpCTE(ParentEmpId, Id, [Name], [Level]) AS
(
    SELECT ParentEmpId, Id, [Name], 0 AS [Level]
    FROM emp
    WHERE id = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT E.ParentEmpId, E.Id, E.[Name], [Level] + 1
    FROM emp E
        INNER JOIN EmpCTE empCTE
        ON E.ParentEmpId = EmpCTE.id
),
EmpCTE2(ParentEmpId, Id, [Name], [Level]) AS
(
    SELECT ParentEmpId, Id, [Name], 0 AS [Level]
    FROM emp
    WHERE id = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT E.ParentEmpId, E.Id, E.[Name], [Level] + 1
    FROM emp E
        INNER JOIN EmpCTE2 empCTE2
        ON E.id = EmpCTE2.ParentEmpId
)
SELECT * FROM EmpCTE
UNION 
SELECT * FROM EmpCTE2
ORDER BY [name]
```

In this **[updated DB Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fee35/44)**, when given `id = 2`, the query returns:

```
ParentEmpId  Id  Name  Level
(null)       1   A     1
1            2   B     0
2            4   D     1
2            5   E     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this way?

```
select data.*
from emp e
  cross apply (
    select * 
    from emp e1
    where e1.Id=e.Id
    union all
    select *
    from emp e2
    where e2.ParentEmpId=e.Id
    union all
    select e4.*
    from emp e3
      join emp e4
        on e3.ParentEmpId=e4.Id
    where e3.Id=e.Id
  ) data
where e.Id=3
```